# getLocationOnScreen crashes

Tags: java, android

I need to get the coordinates of my app on screen to use them as an offset for a popout.

```
                    View tempView = (View) findViewById(R.layout.main);
                    int[] loc = {0,0};
                    tempView.getLocationOnScreen(loc); /// crashes here!
```

Tried this code, but the last line of it makes the app crash. Maybe the tempView I'm getting from the main layout somehow doesn't correspond with the layout on screen?

Any suggestions... thanks! :)

---

added:
solved

```
                    int[] loc = new int[2]; 
                    View tempView = (View) findViewById(R.id.LL_whole);
                    tempView.getLocationOnScreen(loc);

                    post( String.valueOf(loc[1]) );
```

works! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try checking to see if tempView is null.  I suspect findViewById() is failing to find the id you've given it.

```
int[] loc = {0,0};
View tempView = (View) findViewById(R.layout.main);
if (tempView != null) {
    tempView.getLocationOnScreen(loc);
} else {
    Log.d("YourComponent", "tempView was null.");
}
```

In your XML you have something like this:

```
<SomeLayout android:id="@+id/myLayout" ... >

    <SomeView android:id="@+id/myView" ... />
    <SomeOtherView android:id="@+id/myOtherView" .../>

</SomeLayout>
```

So you want to say:

```
SomeView v = (SomeView)findViewById(R.id.myView);
```

Or perhaps:

```
SomeLayout l = (SomeLayout)findViewById(R.id.myLayout);
```

Comment: yes, gives out a null. :) should I findViewById something else, other then main ?

Comment: Yeah, the id of the view you want to find.

Answer (score 1):

findViewById(R.layout.main)

You should place here R.id.something not R.layout.something.